# Show that $Im(\phi) = \mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x]\to \mathbb{C}$ and $\phi(f(x)) = f(i),  \forall f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x].$ Show that $Im(\phi) = \mathbb{Z}[i]$

**My attempt:** I am not sure if it's correct: First, we need to show that $Im(\phi) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Let, $f(x) \in Im(\phi)$ s.t. $f(x) = a+ bx$. Since, $\phi$ is a surjective(also injective) right homomorphism, $\exists f(i) = a+bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ s.t. $\phi(f(x)) = f(i) = a+bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Hence, $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$

But, I don't know how to show the other way, which is to show that $\mathbb{Z}[i] \subseteq Im(\phi)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, what you've showed already is closer to a proof of the *other* inclusion.

To show that $Im(\phi)\subseteq\Bbb Z[i],$ you should start with an arbitrary $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x],$ then show that $f(i)\in\Bbb Z[i].$ It will probably help to first write $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ where $a_0,\dots,a_n\in\Bbb Z.$

For the other inclusion, you will instead start with an arbitrary element of $\Bbb Z[i],$ say $a+bi,$ where $a,b\in\Bbb Z.$ Then you'll want to choose some $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $f(i)=a+bi,$ which is pretty much what you've already done.

Note that we cannot use injectivity or surjectivity of $\phi:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb C.$ It turns out that it *isn't* either of those.

Comment: So, for the first part, how can we go from $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_{k}x^{k}$  to $f(i) \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Well, given such an $f(x),$ what ***is*** $f(i)$?

Comment: $f(i)$ would be $\phi(f(x)) =\sum_{k=0}^{n}  a_{k}i^{k}$. Is that it? Then again, I don't exactly understand how is that going to help us.

Comment: Well, what is $i^0$? $i^1$? $i^2$? $i^3$? $i^4$? $i^5$? $i^6$? $i^7$? $i^8$? (Getting the idea?)

Comment: Oh gosh! sometimes I can be real dumb :) Thanks so much. I get it now.

Comment: Good deal! The obvious can sometimes be hilariously easy to miss. :-/

Comment: Sorry to keep asking so many questions. But, to show the other way, I don't understand how come showing $\phi(f(x)) = f(i) = a+bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ would help to prove $\mathbb{Z}[i] \subseteq Im(\phi)$? Or, are we supposed to do it like this: Let, $f(i) = a+bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ And then, $f(i) = a+bi = \phi(f(x))$ . Thus, $f(i) \in Im(\phi)$?

Comment: You're close. We *started* with $a+bi\in\Bbb Z[x].$ We then chose $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $\phi\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=a+bi.$ What, then, can we say about $a+bi$?

Comment: You mean $a + bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, right? Then, $\phi(f(x)) = a + bi = f(i)$. And thus, $f(x) \in Im(\phi)$. Is that it? If not, then I am lost.

Comment: Oops! I do mean $a+bi\in\Bbb Z[i].$ And then $a+bi\in Im(\phi),$ as you (probably) surmised.

Comment: You're very welcome! Thank *you* for showing your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an euclidean division by $x^2+1$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$. Thus, for any polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbf Z[x]$, you have:
$$f(x)\equiv a+bx\mod x^2+1,\quad (a,b\in\mathbf Z).$$
This prove any $f(\mathrm i)$ is equal to some $a+b\mkern1.5mu\mathrm i$. For the converse, there's nothing to prove.